# how to point from a subdomain to a dedicated ip in my home isp account

Tags: iis, dns, webserver, subdomain, redirect

i need to point from my hosting account to my local server 
so i thought the best way is to do it using a subdomain 
though the issue is that i cant figure which is the right way to do it 
using same DNS as my domain / leaving it blank 
using my internet isp dns maybe ?

what is the right way to point a subdomain to a static ip of my isp internet account at home ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subdomain, you need an A record (address). You could set up a subdomain, and then use an A record within that, so, if your domain is `example.com`:

Your domain is set up as `example.com`, your public web server A record might be `www.example.com`. You could then set up your home server A record as `homeserver.example.com`

A sub domain might be 'home.example.com`, and a server in the sub domain will have an A record of myserver.home.example.com.

In all these cases the IP address of your A record should be the IP address of the network side (external side) of your home internet router. If the address is static this will work, but if it's not you'll need to subscribe to a DNS service that supports Dynamic DNS, and that's a whole different story.

How you go about setting all this up is ISP-dependent.

Note that the external address of your network will not match the internal address of your server, so you'll need to set up port-mapping on the router to allow inbound traffic to reach your server.

..and lastly, do you really want to risk opening up your home network to the ravages of the public internet? Do this **only** if you really know what you're doing, and possibly not even then.

Comment: the second part including the warning is understood and appreciated (i will look into that hacking possible problems) ..as this setup is temp till i will get a vps. the first part which is the most importent i did not realy understand: www.example.com is main domain, home.example.com is a sub, first i am adding the sub, then it is automatically assiggnd values of the hosting service, do i delete dnsess or leave them as they are, do i just add a new record ? i guess this is the confusing part adding record vs deleting/editing  any /which of default ones

Comment: You're confusing domains and addresses. A domain is just a sort of 'container' in which to put your DNS records. `www.example.com` would be an address (A record) in your domain (of your web server). If you want to add another server you could set up another address like `homeserver.example.com` - an A record that points at your home network. Subdomains are an administrative tool to group related items. You might use `london.example.com` for everything in London, and a server might then be `someserver.london.example.com`. I don't think you need that here.

Comment: thanks mate , i understand now and it works(*greate thanks) , though so long `a.b.c.com` i thougt i could do it via simple `sub.domain.com` (i could if i would made it a website which is one of the options though i did not want anything to do with the code on serverthatsonline) so all in all i am happy, its my first webserver at home !! (Hackers be gentel, you can spy but dont get me in truble nor waist my bandwidth) but i will learn how to defend my self soon!
thanks alot Mike!